# when I run this code it shows error

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

```
filename='metamorphosis_clean.txt'

file=open(filename,'rt')

text=file.read()

file.close()


from nltk import sent_tokenize

sentences=sent_tokenize(text)

print(sentences[0])

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "split_into_sentenes.py", line 1, in <module>
    import nltk

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 114, in <module>
    from nltk.collocations import *

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/collocations.py", line 37, in <module>
    from nltk.probability import FreqDist
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/probability.py", line 47, in <module>
    from collections import defaultdict, Counter
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/collections.py", line 13, in <module>
    import pydoc
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pydoc.py", line 56, in <module>
    import sys, imp, os, re, types, inspect, __builtin__, pkgutil, warnings
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 39, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tokenize.py", line 39, in <module>
    COMMENT = N_TOKENS
NameError: name 'N_TOKENS' is not defined
```

Comment: Can you show the full stack trace please

Comment: yeah.can you tell me why its shows  this kind of error.i didn't get it

Comment: are you mixing python 2 and 3? Your stack trace mentions python2.7, while your use of `print()` implies python3

Comment: @joelb `from __future__ import print_function` - recommended if one has to use Python 2 for some reason.

Comment: @joelb this use of print implies nothing ([docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print): print is a function)

Answer (score 1):

In all likelihood you have a file named `token.py` in the current directory, i.e. the directory from which you are running your `split_into_sentenes.py` script.

If present locally, `token.py` will be imported before the one in the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/token.html#module-token), and this would result in the error that you see.

Check whether it exists and if necessary rename it to something that doesn't clash with the standard library.